# What was the most significant change Americans experienced during the 1830s?

Tags: united-states, colonial-america

What would you say was the most striking or best-remembered change for people living in the United States were experiencing during the 1830s, that were different from those of most other eras? I'm not really sure what kinds of changes (political, religious, etc.) were going on at this time, and would like to know more about these changes and how they affected Americans during this time.

This was a time of upheaval that was unusual in America. Why would that have been the case?

Comment: The problem with a question like this is it has no single answer. Good for a discussion forum, but not for here. You should look over the [ask] section of the help area.

Comment: Skim the Wikipedia page in the 1830's and then ask about an event that interests you.

Comment: According to William Strauss and Neil Howe in "Generations," the 1830s were a relatively peculiar (but occasionally recurring) type of time in American history. It was the 19th century version of the 1960s, which featured Woodstock and the "Summer of Love." In this regard, the 1830s are better defined than most other decades in American history. It's worth exploring that definition. Vote to re-open.

Comment: IMHO, still too broad, too opinion based.  At a minimum, the question should reference the new source and summarize the argument.  Otherwise the answer will repeat research that has been done but not documented.

Comment: I would say forcing tens of thousands of Americans off of their lands was a pretty significant change.

Comment: @rougon: I agree. Would you join me in voting to reopen so we can answer the question?

Comment: @TomAu I think it's too vague, really.  What is "change"?  Who are "Americans"?  You can't answer what the most significant change is, since there were so many for so many different types of people.

Comment: @rougon: I made it "striking or best-remembered change for people living in the United States." I assume that your comment refers to native Americans.

Comment: I just think the nature of the question is too vague. It's a whole decade, there are lots of changes (industrial, cultural, social, political, intellectual), and lots of peoples. Yes, Native Americans would have a particular perspective. Slaves another. New Yorkers another. South Carolinians another. And this is assuming we're talking only about the United States.